# ListView lagging/jumping when scrolling up

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-listview

I used [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/) to parse some JSON into a ListView and lazy load the images. It works perfectly when scrolling down, but when scrolling up, the ListView jumps downward on almost every other swipe.

I found another question on here from someone with the same problem but most of the answers suggested using an image loading library, which I already am right? From reading it though, it seems like it's not caching the images(?).

My code is slightly altered from the example, but only the data received from the JSON and the layout is different, so I don't think that would affect the functionality.

Are there any obvious errors with the tutorial I used?

Thanks, Oli.